# Angular JS: Store objects from one array to different arrays/services

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I just started to develop a pretty simple app in Angular JS with a service/factory that holds data that I'm able to push objects to.

I have an array of different people (see html) that you can add as a candidates using the *addCandidate()* function located in the factory.

My problem is that I want to be able to store people/objects from that array into more than one array, e.g. *candidates2 and candidates3* depending on which route/controller is active.

Am I on the right track or should I think completely different?

Factory and controllers:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('Candidates', function (){

  var candidates = [];

  /* I want to fill this array with objects from myCtrl2 */
  var candidates2 = [];

  return{

    addCandidate: function(candidate){
      candidates.push(candidate);
    }

    /* More functions related to Candidates */

  }
});

app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, Candidates){

  $scope.addCandidate = function(candidate){
   Candidates.addCandidate(candidate);
  }

});

/* I want to push candidates to candidates2 here */

app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, Candidates){

  $scope.addCandidate = function(candidate2){
   Candidates.addCandidate(candidate2);
  }

});

/* More controllers of same kind */
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="person in people">
      <h2>{{ person.name }}</h2>
      <button ng-click="addCandidate(person)">Add candidate</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want candidates to be different for each controller. In that case, make the factory build an object constructor (similar to a class, but not really) rather than giving the same object every time.

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2x36Ixps8ruNTFe376dc?p=preview) for an example. Notice that each controller requests and news it's own Candidate, rather than using a shared Candidate definition.

Comment: That really helped, its just that I want the data in the array to be available throughout different routes (even if you go back to route 1). If i return to route 1 with controller 1 from another route the factory will build a new candidates object with an empty array and print that out instead of the added candidates.

Comment: So if I understand, there will be many instances of these array, and each instance needs to persist? I would make one service that handles the Candidate management, and another one that creates and persists these Candidate objects based on a name or something. Then each controller requests the latter service, and requests, by name, the Candidate object that it needs.